# How to tackle arbitrary length lists as input and output in Cython

Tags: python, list, cython, random

I am looking for general advice on how to handle in cython what I would handle with lists in python. For example (a pared down version of what I'm trying to do) in python would be:

```
L = [randint(1, 3) for i in range(randint(1, 30))]
L
def f(X):
  return [i for i in X if not i==0]
K = f(L)
K
```

I've 'found' how to set definite length arrays(?) `cdef int[n]` in cython (obviously trying to use c datatypes) but I can't see how  to get it playing nice when the length of the input and output is arbitrary.

---

EDIT: you can do `cdef list foo = [1,2,3]`. Possibly there're better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Cython is already optimized for built-in types such as lists](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html#for-loops). The most convenient way to achieve what you want is:

```
from random import randint

def main(int num):
    cdef list mylist=[]
    cdef int i

    for i in range(num):
        mylist.append(randint(1, 3))

    return mylist
```

which can be timed with a list comprehension approach so show how the latter is already optimized!

```
In [14]: timeit main(1000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 ms per loop

In [15]: timeit [randint(1, 3) for i in range(1000)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 ms per loop
```